# Densities of the reciprocals of polynomials in binary power series

Tags: co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory

Define the density $[f(z)]$ of a power series $f(z) = f_0+f_1z+f_2z^2+\cdots$ in the binary power series ring $F_2[[z]]$ as the natural density of the set $E_f := \{i : f_i = 1\}.$

$D := \{[f^{-1}] : 0 \in E_f\}$ is the set of densities of the reciprocals of the polynomials with non-zero constant term.

I think every arithmetic sequence has the form $E_{f^{-1}}$ where $f(z)$ is a polynomial with $f(0)=1$

1) Any insight into whether $D$ is nowhere dense or not ? What are the accumulation points of $D$ ?

2) Any insight into upper bounds for $D$ ? $\inf(D)=0$, $\sup(D)=1$

I remember some of this brought up in Cooper & Bryant's "Reciprocals Of Binary Power Series" lead by questions on the parity of the partition function and among other things the densities of the reciprocals of polynomials.

Comment: Isn't the inverse of the polynomial $1-z$ the power series $1+z+z^2+z^3+\cdots$ with density one?

Comment: Perhaps the OP already knows that $0$ and $1$ are limit points of $D$ and is asking about whether $(0,1)$ contains any limit points.

Comment: @GregMartin Why are 0 and 1 limit points?

Comment: $0$ is a limit point for $f_n(x) = 1+x^n$. I don't know about $1$ as a limit point.

Comment: Yes, thank you Gerry. In 1) I meant to ask for insights (including any characterization of limit points) on whether the interior of the closure of D is non-empty. My intuition tells me 1 may be a limit point. Thank you again.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, any binary polynomial $f\in F_2[x]$ has a multiple of the form $1+x^m$, so its reciprocal writes $1/f=g/(1+x^m)$, $g$ being the co-factor of $f$. Therefore $D$ may also be described as the set of fractions $k/m$ where $m$  are positive integers and $k$ are the possible number of terms of  factors of $1+x^m$. The question then would be rephrased as: how may terms can a factor of $1+x^m$ in$F_2[x]$ have?

Comment: (above: a binary polynomial **with f(0)=1**, of course)

Comment: @Pietro. $1+z^m$ has finitely many polynomial factors of positive degree. f need not be one of them. If the cofactor g is not a polynomial, which is generally the case, then perhaps you mean the entire group of units in $F_2[[z]]$ when you write on factors of $1+z^m$.

Comment: @Oliver Kayende In my comment above, $m$ depends on $f$ (that is $\forall f\exists m$). For instance $1+x+x^5$ divides $1+x^{21}$ and $1+x+x^9$ divides $1+x^{73}$

Comment: And if $fg=1+x^m$, the natural density of the nonzero coefficients in the series of $1/f=\frac{g}{1+x^m}$ is the number of non-zero coefficients of $g$ divided by $m$ (just because $1/f=g+x^mg+x^{2m}g+x^{3m}g+\dots,$ repeats periodically the coefficients of $g$ with period $m$)

Comment: Also note: Since $1+x^m$ divides $1+x^{mn}$  for any $n$, the rational function $\frac{g}{1+x^{mn}}$ is also a reciprocal of a polynomial. As a consequence, if $q\in D$ then $q/n\in D$, for any positive integer $n$.

Comment: What do you mean by the "number of non-zero coefficients of $g$" when $g$ is not a polynomial ?

Comment: Here $f$ and $g$ are both polynomials.

Comment: @PietroMajer: you assume that there are no overflows during multiplication of polynomials, which is almost never the case. I suppose that you really mean $\dfrac{1}{1+x+x^4} = \dfrac{1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^5 + x^7 + x^8 + x^{11}}{1 + x^{15}}$ ($1 + x^{15}$ instead of $1 + x^{21}$ in the last denominator). If you substitute $2$ for $x$ here, you will get that $19 \cdot 2479 = 47101$, not $2^{15} + 1 = 32769$. Moreover, $2479$ is not even a divisor of $2^{15} + 1$ (or of $2^{21} + 1$, for that matter).

Comment: @ Kaban-5 right, I removed the last comment that was incorrect or unclear, and had a couple of typos.

Comment: (Maybe I'll rewrite it more clearly;  I think the statements were correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I claim that all the fractions $\frac{1}{2t}$ are accumulation points of densities.

This follows from $2$ claims. Recall that $a(x)$ of degree $m$ over $F_2$ is **primitive** if $a(x)$ is a factor of $x^{2^m-1}+1$ but not $x^N+1$ for any smaller $N.$

- If $a(x)$ is a primitive polynomial of degree $m$ over $F_2$ then $\frac{1}{a(x)}$ has density $\frac{2^{m-1}}{2^m-1}.$
- The density of $\frac1{a(x^t)}$ is $\frac1t$ times the density of $\frac1{a(x)}.$

It will help to consider all proper ratios of polynomials $\frac{n(x)}{a(x)}$ over $F_2$ where $a(x)$ should have constant term $1$ and greater degree than $n(x).$ We do not insist that the ratio be in reduced form. Every such ratio, expressed as a series, is periodic, so the densities are rational numbers.

---

**OPTIONAL COMPUTATIONAL DIGRESSION** This computation wasn't as helpful as I expected. But I preserve it for what it is worth

There are $2047$ monic polynomials of positive degree $11$ or less with constant term $1.$ Their reciprocal power series enjoy $149$ distinct densities :

[image]

There is  an accumulation point at $0$ at also one at $\frac12.$  I don't visually see any other strong candidates from that data.

Of the $149$ densities, $99$ are in the interval  $[\frac37,\frac6{11}].$ Here is a graph:

[image]

Curious fact: At least up to $k=6$, the density of$\frac1{1+x+x^{2^k}}$ is $\frac{3^k-1}{4^k-1}.$

**END OF DIGRESSION**

---

Let $$g_{\infty}(x)=\frac1{1+x}=1+x+x^2+\cdots$$ Then

$$\frac1{1+x^N}=g_{\infty}(x^N)$$ has density $\frac1{N}.$

This is the unique way to get the largest possible density,  $1.$ It also shows that $0$ is an accumulation point of densities.

Define $g_N(x)=\frac{1+x^N}{1+x}=1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{N-1}.$ then $$\frac1{g_N(x)}=(1+x)(1+x^N+x^{2N}+\cdots)$$ has density $\frac2{N}.$

This gives the second highest density in the small computation above, $\frac1{1+x+x^2}$ has density $\frac23.$ I'd wildly conjecture that these are the only reciprocal polynomials giving densities in $[\frac23,1].$

Also, $$\frac1{g_N(x^j)}=(1+x^j)(1+x^{Nj}+x^{2Nj}+\cdots)$$ has density $\frac{2}{Nj}.$

This provides the only occurrences of the smallest densities in the modest computation above $1/11, 1/10, 1/9, 1/8, 2/15, 1/7, 1/6, 2/11.$

---

To justify the two claims above I will first give two examples and then discuss the general situation.

Let $a(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $4$ with constant term $1.$ There are $2^4-1=15$ proper rational functions $\frac{n(x)}{a(x)}.$ Of them, $8$ have numerator of degree $3$, call them **tails**. Also, $8$ have constant term $1$, call them **heads**. There are 4 that are both heads and tails. Here are paths from each tail to its matching head. The rule is that $$\frac{xn(x)}{a(x)}\rightarrow \frac{n(x)}{a(x)}.$$ The strings on the left will be used later.

$$0001 \hspace{1in} {\frac {{x}^{3}}{a(x)}}\rightarrow{\frac {{x}^{2}}{a(x)}}\rightarrow{\frac {x}{a(x)}}\rightarrow\frac1{a(x)} \tag{A}$$

$$001 \hspace{1in}{\frac {{x}^{2}+{x}^{3}}{a(x)}}\rightarrow{\frac {{x}+x^2}{a(x)}}\rightarrow{
\frac {1+x}{a(x)}}\tag{B}$$

$$01 \hspace{2in}{\frac {x+{x}^{3}}{a(x)}}\rightarrow{\frac {1+{x}^{2}}{a(x)}}\tag{C}$$

$$01 \hspace{1in}{\frac {x+{x}^{2}+x^3}{a(x)}}\rightarrow{\frac {1+x+{x}^{2}}{a(x)}}\tag{D}$$

$$1 \hspace{3in}{\frac {1+{x}^{3}}{a(x)}}\tag{E}$$

$$1 \hspace{3in}{\frac {1+x+{x}^{3}}{a(x)}}\tag{F}$$

$$1 \hspace{3in}{\frac {1+x^2+{x}^{3}}{a(x)}}\tag{G}$$

$$1 \hspace{3in}{\frac {1+x+x^2+{x}^{3}}{a(x)}}\tag{H}$$

These paths are independent of $a(x).$ Then each head is connected to a tail according to a rule which does depend on $a(x).$ The result will be one or more cycles, some perhaps of length $1.$ To find the successor of $\frac{n(x)}{a{x}}$ take $n(x)+a(x)$, which will have degree $4$ and constant term $0,$ say $n(x)+a(x)=xn'(x).$ Then $$\frac{n(x)}{a(x)}\rightarrow \frac{n'(x)}{a(x)}.$$

Here is the results for $a(x)=1+x+x^3+x^4$ (on the left) and for $a(x)=1+x+x^4$ (on the right)

[image]

Starting on the left, the cycle $AGF$ (started at the head of $A$) with corresponding string $1\, 1\, 1\, 000$ (spaces for clarity but optional) tells us that $(1+x+x^2)(1+x+x^3+x^4)=1+x^6$ so $$\frac{1}{1+x+x^3+x^4}=\frac{1+x+x^2}{1+x^6} $$ with density $\frac36.$

The cycle $HD$ with string $101$ tells us that $(1+x^2)(1+x+x^3+x^4)=(1+x+x^2)(1+x^4)$ so $$\frac{1+x+x^2}{1+x+x^3+x^4}=\frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4}$$ with density $\frac24.$

Moving to the right, the polynomial $1+x+x^4$ is seen to create one big cycle with string $1\,1\,1\,1\,01\,01\,1\,001\,000$ this tells us that $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^5+x^7+x^8+x^{11} )(1+x+x^4 )=1+x^{15}$ so $$\frac1{1+x+x^4}=\frac{1+x+x^2+x^3+x^5+x^7+x^8+x^{11}}{1+x^{15}}$$ with density $\frac8{15}.$

Because $1+x+x^4$ is primitive, it doesn't divide $1+x^N$ for any positive $N \lt 15.$ Accordingly the cycle, whatever it is, uses all eight strings and has density $\frac8{15}$.

Note that we can discover $a(x)$ as soon as we see one link so $C \rightarrow B$ means $(1+x^2)+a(x)=x(x^2+x^3)=x^3+x^4$ meaning $a(x)=1+x^2+x^3+x^4.$ That might or might not make a single cycle so not every way to link the strings into a single cycle comes from a polynomial.

---

In general, for a primitive polynomial $a(x)$ of degree $m,$ the density of the reciprocal is $$\frac{2^{m-1}}{2^m-1}$$ because in computing $\frac1{a(x)}$ every non-zero proper ratio $\frac{n(x)}{a(x)}$ is seen as a remainder before the period is done.

Comment: It seems you are using a notion of natural density that differs from the OP's. As I understand, he defines  the density of a power series $f(z)\in F_2[[z]]$ as $$[f(z)]:=\lim_n\frac{\text{card}\{i\in\mathbb{N}\,:\, 0\le i<n ,\, f_i=1\}}{n}$$ that e.g. gives density 1 to ${1\over 1+x}$ and $2/3$ to ${1\over 1+x+x^2}$.

Comment: @PietroMajer But $1/(1+x)=1+x^2+x^4+\cdots$ so isn’t that density 1/2? Similarly, why 2/3?

Comment: Am I missing spmething? Isn't $1/(1+x)=1/(1-x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots$ with $F_2$ coefficients? That 2/3 because $1/(1+x+x^2)={1+x\over 1+x^3}=1+x+0x^2+x^3+ x^4+0x^5+...$

Comment: No, you were right. Now it is fixed

Comment: @Meyerowitz. Ok but where did you show that b'(z) has "weight" exactly $2^{m-1}$ ?

Comment: The $\Bbb F_2[[z]]$ ring endomorphism $\phi : f(z) \rightarrow f(z^n)$ is injective maps $\Bbb F_2[z]$ back on itself with the obvious general property $$[\phi (f(z))] = \frac {1}{n} * [f(z)]$$ Therefore, after you show that the numerator in the end of your post is $2^{m-1}$ then with the last point made I believe D would actually be dense in (0,1).

Comment: @OliverKayende I added an example and made some small corrections.

Comment: @Meyerowitz. The example is fine. Your last claim about the density $\frac {2^{m-1}}{2^m-1}$ for all m is the most concerning. Do you have proof or is it conjecture from the data ?

Comment: @Meyerowitz. From what I read the density demonstrated is of the form $\frac {k}{2^m-1}$ where $k$ is the number of non-zero coefficients of b'(x). But you never explained why b'(x) has $2^{m-1}$ non-zero coefficients. Thank you for your insights.

Comment: @OliverKayende I managed with just $b(x).$ Given that the period is $2^m-1$, we cycle through that many distinct $m$ bit states, so all but $000..0$, once each. $2^{m-1}$ of them start with $1.$

Comment: @Meyerowitz. I agree $N=2^m-1$ is the period of the power series $$a(z)=\frac{b(z)}{1+z^N}$$ you posted. I agree $[a(z)]=\frac{k}{N}$ where $k$ is the exact # terms in $b(z)$. However, there are exactly $2^N$ different periodic power series of period $N$ which far exceeds the number $P_{N}$ of polynomial reciprocals of period $N$. This is because $P_{N}$ equals the exact number of polynomial factors of $1+z^{N}$.

Comment: @OliverKayende You can check it on (lots of) examples too, but the proof seems good .

Comment: @Meyerowitz. I need to see proof not examples. You have NOT proven $b(x)$ has exactly $2^{m-1}$ terms anywhere in your post which I've kindly taken the time to reread several times in search of this very proof. Would you please kindly point to the part of the proof that proves that $b(x)$ has exactly $2^{m-1}$ terms ? No examples. You cannot prove this by example.

Comment: Take $m=6.$ The $64$ states with $6$ bits (or $7$ bits with last bit $1$) are evenly split, $32$ start with $1$ and $32$ start with $0$ including $000000$ which we discard. If you have $a(x)$ of degree $6$ and period $63$ then you cycle through those $63$ states in some particular order and you will get $k=32$ for a density of $\frac{32}{63}.$ That is the proof.

Comment: @OliverKayende make that $7$ bit states that end in $0.$

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz. That is not the proof. Not all of those states your "cycling" through correspond to reciprocals of polynomials. You can't pick any state you want. In fact the polynomial reciprocals make a small percentage of the states you're "cycling" through. Why do you assume "cycling" must yield a polynomial reciprocal ? It will certainly yield a "state" but that "state" need not be the state of a polynomial inverse. The state space is closed under + but the family of polynomial inverses is not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer below. I reworked this (and corrected irreducible to primitive) . I hope it is convincing. I replaced states with remainders (which is the same). Yes, every polynomial ratio (or reciprocal) creates a cycle of states but not every cycle comes from a polynomial. However if the denominator is a primitive degree m$ then the cycle which does arise uses all the states. (cont)

Comment: Somewhat like this fact: There are $120$ ways to cycle through $1/7,2/7,3/7,4/7,5/7,6/7$ only six of them could come from working out the decimal for a  $k\7,$ but they all do have period $6$. This because $7 \mid 10^6$ but not $10^N-1$ for any smaller $N.$

Answer (score 1):

I felt this synopsis of Aaron Meyerowitz's post with Pietro Majer's comment and my own might be useful, possibly even insightful, in characterizing $D$ even further.

$A(z)=\sum_{0}^{\infty} a_iz^i\in \Bbb F_2[[z]]$ is called *periodic* by any of the following equivalent definitions :

1. For some $n\in\Bbb N,B(z)\in\Bbb F_2[z]$ with $deg(B(z))<n$ we have $$A(z)*(1+z^n)=B(z)$$ (The *period* $d$ of $A(z)$ is the smallest possible value for $n$ while $k$ is the exact number of terms in $B(z)$)
2. $E_A$ is the union of $k$ distinct arithmetic sequences of the same common difference $n$.
3. $(a_i)_i^\infty$ is a periodic sequence of period $d$, which divides $n$, and has exactly $k$ 1s up to its first $n$ coefficients.

   - Therefore, there are exactly $2^n$ periodic power series whose period divides $n$. Each periodic power series whose period divides $n$ has the form $\frac{B(z)}{1+z^n}$ and has density $\frac{k}{n}$ where $k$ is the number of nonzero coefficients in $B(z)$. Of these the polynomial reciprocals are the reciprocals of the non-constant factors of $1+z^n$ and thus each of the form $\frac{b(z)}{1+z^n}$ where $b(z)$ is a proper divisor of $1+z^n$.
   - Therefore $D=${$\frac{k}{n}:$ $n\in\Bbb N,$ $b(z)$ has exactly $k$ terms and properly divides $1+z^n$} as each invertible polynomial $f(z)$ divides the characteristic polynomial $\psi_m(z)=z+z^{2^m}$ of its splitting field $\Bbb F_{2^m}$ where $m = deg(f(z))$ when $f$ is irreducible over $\Bbb F_2$.

**Claim** *(Meyerowitz)* : Given $m\in\Bbb N$ there exists a $2^{m-1}$ term polynomial $b(z)$ that divides $1+z^{2^m-1}$.

Assuming this claim then $\frac{2^j}{c(2^k-1)}\in D$ for all $c,j,k\in\Bbb N$ with $j<k$ because the $\Bbb F_2[[z]]$ ring endomorphism $\phi_n : f(z)\rightarrow f(z^n)$ has the obvious property $$[\phi_n(f(z))]=\frac{1}{n}*[f(z)]$$ for all binary power series $f(z)$.